# Can I use SOCKS5 in FTP batch file on Windows?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, proxy, ftp, socks

I want to use a SOCKS5 connection with a generic proxy to upload files to FTP.

I'm working on Windows server. My `.txt` for my `.bat` actually looks like:

```
open proxyhost
proxyuser
proxypassword
user ftpuser@ftphost.de
ftppassword
bin
mput \\upload\path\to\*.pdf

quit
```

I'm opening the `.txt` file with:

```
ftp -i -s:"\\path\to\mytxt.txt" >"\\path\to\ftp.log" 
find "226" "\\path\to\ftp.log" && goto finished || goto error
:finished
exit 0
:error
exit 1
```

Now the question: Is there a way to use SOCKS5 in this `.txt`?

I found nothing on Google.

Maybe you can help me out. Thanks a lot.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows built-in `ftp.exe` FTP client does not support any kind of proxies (the FTP proxy you are using in your script is a transparent proxy, the FTP client does not even know it exists).

---

You have to use another command-line FTP client.

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation):

```
winscp.com /log="\\path\to\ftp.log" /command ^
    "open ftp://ftpuser:ftppassword@ftphost.de/ -rawsettings ProxyMethod=2 ProxyHost=proxyhost ProxyUsername=proxyuser ProxyPassword=proxypassword" ^
    "put \\upload\path\to\*.pdf" ^
    "exit"
if errorlevel 1 goto error
exit 0
:error
exit 1
```

For details see:

- the [guide for converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).
- documentation for the ["raw session settings"](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings) for the proxy.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helped me out :)